# How to style the indicators in Bootstrap slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the local environment, we changed the CSS for the round indicators for the slider and it works great. When we upload, the packages get updated from GitHub and we loose our changes.

We handle that by adding our own CSS file and styling upon Bootstrap's. This works great for the components that we have an ID for. However, we're not clear on the ID of the dotty thingies that function as indicator on the slider.

How do I find their ID so I can add my own class upon the one provided by Bootstrap?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>
  ...
```

Comment: So I assume you're using the Bootstrap carousel and you are interested in changing the CSS of the navigation dots by selecting their IDs? Please insert the code snippets for the carousel and the CSS you're using to edit it.

Comment: @arch1ve There you go. As you can see, i can only reference them by class, not by id. And setting an explicit class, I fear, will override the internal settings of them. Maybe we won't see the issue now but later on, I'll be crying a river because of something stupid I've done in the beginning, making it hard to diagnose the **future** weirdnesses.

Comment: You can simply add a `class` attribute to all of the navigation dots without overriding bootstrap's settings. The `active` class is added via JavaScript at the end of all existing classes anyway.

Comment: That easy? Cool. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a `class` attribute to all of the navigation dots without overriding bootstrap's settings. The `active` class is added via JavaScript at the end of all existing classes anyway.